# Multiple Mongo Aggregation Query Performance Improvement

Tags: mongodb

I have 5 mongo db aggregator queries. Each query has same group part but different match criteria.
forexample :

```
1- count records by email
2- count records by phone
3- count records by xxx...
```

```
db.getCollection("myCol").aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
                   
               { "contact.email": "mytestEmail@gmail.com" }
                 //.. some more conditions       
                
        }
    }
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$myId",
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    }
    
])
```

each query is very fast (as index is being scanned) but since i need to call these group of 5 queries multiple times (say 5* 37) so its making the end-to-end api very slow .

what is the best appriach for this in mongo db ? as i am not very expect in mongoDB.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: if there is common match part for some queries and you always need to execute the 5x queries together perhaps try to combine them in a single  $facet aggregation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down the performance area's your describing:

1. Application network (Client -> App calls)
2. DB network (App -> db calls)
3. DB processing.

You want to be able to reduce each of them separately.

---

Let's start with the point you're asking about point #3.

Here it Mongo has to scan each index tree separately to count the documents, therefor it doesn't matter if it's 37 different calls, or 1 call using an aggregation.

---

For point #2

Here the amount of calls does matter, as each time to send a request to the DB and wait for it to return there is overhead, it's the reason operations like [bulkWrite](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) exists for example - so you could execute multiple updates while saving the network overhead.

In your case you just want to make sure you're doing a single db call using a single aggregation pipeline.

---

#1 Goes without saying, I'm assuming the client already sends a single call but in the case he does not change it.

Good luck.